# How to add pyplot module in pyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I've got a problem with pyplot. When I try to add it to pyCharm I receive this information:

> Collecting pyplot
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyplot (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for pyplot

System: Windows 7 64bit, Python 3.63

Comment: Have you installed `matplotlib`?

Comment: Yes, I installed matplotlib and pyCharm gave me some trouble.

Comment: Well, what happened when you installed matplotlib. Does running `import matplotlib` give you any errors?

Answer (score 0):

The `pyplot` module is a part of `matplotlib`, therefore you don't install it separately.

Install matplotlib normally:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Then in your code you would use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

or more convieniently:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```